# custom checkbox needs to decide when to draw psalternate border

Tags: windows, delphi, keyboard, controls, vcl

I'm trying to create a custom checkbox control (delphi 2010; based on tstatictext), and i can't figure how to decide if the (psalternate style) border should be drawn around the focused caption. Windows draws this border once the tab key has been pressed, and does not it if the control is focused with the mouse prior to the first tab press (after activating the parent). Any hints?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Just imitate behaviour of the standard `TCheckBox` and draw focus rect *only* after Tab-key has been pressed (this focus rect will be also drawn after CheckBox was clicked and after this another control on the same parent had been selected by keyboard arrow keys)? If so, then catch `MouseDown` event inside of your custom control and raise the flag `DoNotDrawFocusRect`. Then override `CMFOCUSCHANGED` message and check in its handler if flag was raised. If so, then do not paint focus rect, otherwise - draw it. Or I just did get you wrong?

Comment: See WM_QUERYUISTATE and friends.

Comment: @sertac thanks, that seems to solve the issue. the low bit is what i need, and other two might also come handy in the future. if you wish you can post an answer.
dima, it doesn't matter how the focus was last achieved, but if the tab key was pressed at some point before.
Happy new year all. Have luck and health in 2019.